# List<T> derived from IList<T> and from IEnumerable<T>, useless?

Tags: c#, derived-types

From mscorlib.dll:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{..}

public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
{...}
```

Why `List<T>` have to explicitly derived from `ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable,` in addition of derived from `IList<T>` which itself derived from `ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable` ?

Comment: No, that's not from mscorlib.dll. mscorlib.dll doesn't contain C# code. This is from what your decompiler is showing you.

Comment: Check the [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,36)

Comment: Ultimately this is just your decompiler being helpful.  Quite useful to tell in one fell swoop what interfaces are implemented by a class.  Such declarations are ambiguous, a side-effect of the misnomer of "interface inheritance".  C# syntax makes that look too much like the kind of inheritance that makes you richer.  A misnomer because this actually makes you poorer with *more* work you have to do to implement the interface members.  Feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object browser or Reflector or similar don't have the source code, they have metadata to work with. Its not easy to know inspecting that information if a type implements directly an interface or not, so the easy option, because the ultimate goal is documentation, is to simply show all interfaces even if some are redundant.

For more information, read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces/).

Answer (score 5):

Don't trust decompiled code to be an accurate representation of the original source code.

[The original source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html) contains only

> ```
> public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
> ```

So yes, you're right that `List<T>` doesn't need to be explicitly derived from `ICollection<T>` and others. It isn't.